# Python not running a new window until closing another window

Tags: python, webview

Why is Python waiting for you to close one window in order to open another?
Is it impossible to simultaneously open both?
Or why calling a Window in an infinite loop stops this loop until you close the window?

```
    while True:
        webview.create_window('Hello world 1', 'https://gog.com/')
        webview.start()
        #loop waiting until wv is close
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use multiprocessing to accomplish this:

```py
from multiprocessing import Process
processes = []

    while True:
        webview.create_window('Hello world 1', 'https://gog.com/')
        window_process = Proces(target=webview.start, args=())
        window_process.start()
        processes.append(window_process) #So we can quit it later
```

Then at the end of your code, put this to quit the processes neatly:

```py
for process in processes:
    try:
        process.terminate()
        process.join()
    except:
        pass
```